# Deactive components of Symfony2 full stack framework

Tags: php, angularjs, symfony

I would like to do my new Web project on top of two technologies : Symfony2 for the back-end server, and AngularJS for the front-end (sexy, right ? ;)).

I want to make the Symfony2 server as a REST API, which means I won't need a lot of Symfony2 components, such as :

- Forms
- Twig

The problem is that I'm not starting from scratch, which means I already have a Symfony2 full-stack application.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to delete components from the full-stack framework. I've seen that it's pretty simple for Twig component, but I've seen nothing for form.

Do you know if there is a clean way to do that ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your custom symfony2 removing from your composer.json the line (and all you don't need as doctrine...)

```
symfony/symfony
```

and use only your preferred component, you can see the complete list from the [github repo](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/composer.json) . As example you can configure simply:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/finder":           "~2.3",
    "symfony/filesystem":       "~2.3",
    "symfony/options-resolver": "~2.3",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "~2.3"
},
```

The documentation reference for the symfony2 components is [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/index.html)

Take care if you install a bundle that have in the dependences a module that you don't want it will download with him dependencies.

Hope this help.

PS: You should consider to use a microframework like [silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)